# Visual C++ unamanged and managed

Tags: visual-c++, pointers, memory-management, c++-cli

What are the differences between creating an instance of a .NET object in C++ that is managed vs. unmanaged. That is to say, what are the differences between these to statements:

```
StreamWriter ^stream = gcnew StreamWriter(fileName);
```

versus

```
StreamWriter *stream = new StreamWriter(fileName);
```

My assumption is that if I use gcnew, the memory allocated for StreamWriter will be managed by the garbage collector. Alternatively if I use the pointer(*) and new keyword, I will have to call delete to deallocate the memory.

My real question is: will the garbage collector manage the memory that is being allocated inside of the .NET objects? For instance if a .NET object instantiates another object, and it goes out of scope - will the garbage collector manage that memory even if I use the pointer(*) and new keyword and NOT the gcnew and handle(^).

Comment: Your question is unanswerable, the second snippet simply isn't valid code.  An object of a managed class *has* to be allocated with gcnew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an object with **gcnew** it is binded to the garbage collector, and the garbage collector will be responsible for destroying it.

If you use **new** it won't be binded to the garbage collector, and it will be your responsibility to delete the object.

***Just to clarify:***
If you have a managed C# object that contains within it an unmanaged object, the garbage collector will not delete the unmanaged object. It will just call the managed object's destructor (if it exists) before it is deleted. You should write your own code in the destructor to delete the unmanaged objects you created.

Comment: Can I call delete on objects that are managed by the garbage collector, or should I just dereference it? I would think that deleting them manually would be faster.

Comment: You can't delete managed objects, you'll get a compilation error

Comment: Entirely untrue -- you can delete *handles* to managed objects, which has the same semantics as deleting an unmanaged pointer but calls `dispose` instead of calling a destructor.

Comment: How is that different than what i wrote ? You can delete the unmanaged objects, but the GC won't do it implicitly for you.

Answer (score 6):

In C++/CLI, you can't `new` a .NET object, you'll get something similar to the following error:

> error C2750: 'System::Object' : cannot use 'new' on the reference type; use 'gcnew' instead

Usage of `new` for .NET objects is allowed in the older Managed Extensions for C++ (`/clr:oldsyntax` compiler flag).  "Managed C++" is now deprecated because it is horrible.  It has been superceded by C++/CLI, which introduced the `^` and `gcnew`.

In C++/CLI, you must use `gcnew` (and `^` handles) for managed types and you must use `new` (and `*` pointers) for native types.  If you do create objects on the native heap using `new`, it is your responsibility to destroy them when you are done with them.

Ideally you should use a smart pointer (like `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`) to manage the object on the native heap.  However, since you can't have a native smart pointer as a field of a ref class, this isn't entirely straightforward.  The simplest and most generic approach would probably be to write your own smart pointer wrapper ref class that correctly implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: I think the OP means a CLR object with a pointer to a regular C++ object.

Comment: @casablanca:  You can't use `new` to create a managed object, period.  `new StreamWriter(fileName)` is simply not allowed in C++/CLI.

Comment: Ok, I guess both of us missed different parts of the question. You answered the first part (which I initially missed), while I'm talking about the second part, where the OP asks about a CLR object that contains a member pointer to an unmanaged object.

Comment: You can have a smart pointer as a field of a ref class. Just put it private and wrap its methods with C# style methods .